# Prove that for $\alpha\not\in\mathbb{Q},\alpha>0$, $([n+n\alpha])_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sqcup([n+n\alpha^{-1}])_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=\mathbb{N} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

**My Quesion:** Prove that for $\alpha\not\in\mathbb{Q},\alpha>0$, $([n+n\alpha])_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcup([n+n\alpha^{-1}])_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=\mathbb{N}$, where $[k]$ means the integral part of $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $\sqcup$ means disjoint union.

**My Idea:** I just realized that $$\frac{1}{1+\alpha}+\frac{1}{1+\alpha^{-1}}=1, \quad\text{where } 1+\alpha, 1+\alpha^{-1} \text{ are positive irrational numbers}$$
So the interested sequences are [Beatty's sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence#targetText=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20Beatty%20sequence,wrote%20about%20them%20in%201926.&targetText=Beatty%20sequences%20can%20also%20be%20used%20to%20generate%20Sturmian%20words.). And here is a  [proof](http://sections.maa.org/mddcva/MeetingFiles/Spring2016Meeting/TalkSlides/Brown.pdf) (page 11-13) for Beatty sequences.

Comment: You already provided a complete solution to your problem 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You already provided a complete solution to your problem" Yes, I just proved it.

Comment: If you propose a Q and answer it and accept your own answer do you gain reputation points for the acceptance?  I don't really care. I never thought about it.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet No, I can't get any reputation points by answering my own question. Not wanting to draw any further attention to this solved question, I posted my answer to it.