# A Generalization of Beatty's Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

If $t>0,t^2, t+\frac{1}{t},t+t^2,\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{t^2}$ are all irrational number,
$$a_n=n+\left \lfloor \frac{n}{t} \right \rfloor+\left \lfloor \frac{n}{t^2} \right \rfloor,\\
b_n=n+\left \lfloor \frac{n}{t} \right \rfloor +\left \lfloor nt \right \rfloor,\\
c_n=n+\left \lfloor nt \right \rfloor+\left \lfloor nt^2 \right \rfloor, $$
then every positive integer appear exactly once. In other words, the sequences $a_1,b_1,c_1,a_2,b_2,c_2,\cdots$ together contain all the positive integers without repetition.
I have checked every integer from $1$ to $10^6$ for $t=2^\frac{1}{4}$:
$$a_n=1, 4, 7, 9, 12, 15, 16, 19, 22, 25, 27, 30, 32, 34, 37, 40, 43, 45, 47, 50,\dots \\
b_n=2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 18, 20, 23, 26, 29, 33, 36, 38, 41, 44, 48, 51, 54, 56, 59,\dots \\
c_n=3, 6, 10, 13, 17, 21, 24, 28, 31, 35, 39, 42, 46, 49, 53, 57, 61, 64, 67, 71,\dots $$

PS: This is a special case of following statement：

> If $t_1,t_2,\cdots,t_k>0$,and $\forall i \not =j,\frac{t_j}{t_i}$ is irrational,
>   $$a_i(n)=\sum_{j=1}^k{\left \lfloor \frac{t_j}{t_i}n \right \rfloor},i=1,2,\cdots,k,$$
>
> then every positive integer appear exactly once in $a_1(n),\cdots,a_k(n)$.

Comment: Curious! An easy special case is that the claim holds when $t=(1+\sqrt5)/2$. In spite of $1/t+1/t^2$ then being equal to $1$. Then the $a$-sequence covers the odd natural numbers, and the other two partition the even numbers Beatty-style. All because $1+1/t=t$, $1+t=t^2$, and $(t,t^2)$ is a Beatty pair.

Comment: Maybe it holds for all t>0 when t^2 is irrational.

Comment: See [this variant of Beatty](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3382300/11619) from a week earlier. In some texts the Beatty construction is iterated to find partitions into more sequences. The idea is explained in [this old answer by Achille Hui](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/847530/11619). That idea doesn't seem to work here because none of the sequences here are of the Beatty form due to the presence of several floor functions.

Comment: Next, sorry about hijacking your question to an extent with the bounty. If you think you want to see more details and/or other answers I will happily sponsor another round later.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Thanks, I added a more general statement :)

Comment: Incredible thankyou for posting!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edited 10/24.** Now this is largely expanded, probably longer than what it needs to be. TL;DR: Construct a function $f$, record where it ticks. The range of $f$ is exactly $\mathbb N$ and covers $\{a_n\}, \{b_n\}$ and $\{c_n\}$ without repetition.

That is true.

By substituting $t$ by $1/t$ if necessary, assume $t>1$. By adding dummy $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$, we rewrite the sequences as
$$
\begin{aligned}
a_n &= \Big\lfloor\frac{n}{t^2}\Big\rfloor + \Big\lfloor\frac{n}{t}\Big\rfloor + \lfloor n\rfloor,\\
b_n &= \Big\lfloor\frac{n}{t}\Big\rfloor + \lfloor n \rfloor + \lfloor nt\rfloor,\\
c_n &= \lfloor n\rfloor + \lfloor nt\rfloor + \lfloor nt^2\rfloor.
\end{aligned}
$$

This suggests us the following process. We consider a function $$f(\delta) := \lfloor\delta\rfloor + \lfloor\delta t\rfloor + \lfloor\delta t^2\rfloor,$$ and start with $f(1/t^2) = a_1 = 1$. For convenience denote $\delta_1 = 1/t^2$.

Given $\delta_{i-1}$, we will obtain $\delta_i$ by the following process. We increase $\delta$ continuously from $\delta_{i-1}$, until we are in the situation that one of $\delta$, $\delta t$ or $\delta t^2$ hits an integer. Then we will call the new $\delta$ value $\delta_i$. Therefore we get a sequence $$\left\{\delta_1 = \frac1{t^2}, \delta_2, \cdots\right\}.$$

What do the function $f$ and the sequence $\{\delta_i\}$ tell us? Well, lets look at it.

1. $f$ only take values at integers, by the definition, and it is non-decreasing, with $f(\delta_1) = 1$. Therefore by restricting the domain, the range $$f\left(\left[\delta_1, \infty\right)\right) \subseteq \mathbb N.$$
2. In the interval $\delta \in (\delta_{i-1}, \delta_i)$, by the construction of the sequence $\{\delta_i\}$, $\delta, \delta t, \delta t^2$ have the same integral part as $\delta_{i-1}, \delta_{i-1}t, \delta_{i-1}t^2$, respectively. Hence $f(\delta) = f(\delta_{i-1})$. In other words, $\{\delta_i\}$ are the places when $f$ "jump in value". Written in math, $$f(\{\delta_i\}) = f\left(\left[\delta_1, \infty\right)\right) \subseteq \mathbb N.$$
3. For every $\delta_i$ in the sequence, $f(\delta_i)$ is in $\{a_n\}, \{b_n\}$ or $\{c_n\}$, depending on which of $\delta_i, \delta_it$ or $\delta_it^2$ is an integer. For instance, if $\delta_it = n$ is an integer, then $f(\delta_i) = \lfloor n/t\rfloor + \lfloor n\rfloor + \lfloor nt \rfloor = b_n$. So $$f(\{\delta_i\}) \subseteq \{a_n\} \cup \{b_n\} \cup \{c_n\}.$$
4. Converse to 3., whenever $\delta, \delta t$ or $\delta t^2$ is an integer, $\delta \in \{\delta_i\}$. In other words, the sequence $\{\delta_i\}$ can be obtained by merging and sorting the three sequences $\{n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, $\{n/t\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $\{n/t^2\}_{n=1}^\infty$, or $$f(\{\delta_i\} \supseteq \{a_n\}) \cup \{b_n\} \cup \{c_n\}.$$
5. For an integer $i$, $f(\delta_i) = f(\delta_{i-1})+1$. Since $t$ and $t^2$ are irrational, only one of $\delta_{i-1}, \delta_{i-1}t, \delta_{i-1}t^2$ can be an integer. Same when $i-1$ is changed to $i$. Therefore, comparing $f(\delta_{i-1})$ and $f(\delta_i)$, two of the three terms are same (have the same integral part) and the third term jumps to the next integer. Therefore $f(\delta_i) = f(\delta_{i-1})+1$. Together with the fact $f(\delta_1) = 1$, we have $$f(\{\delta_i\}) = \mathbb N.$$ Putting 3., 4., and 5. together, we know that $$\{a_n\}\cup\{b_n\}\cup \{c_n\} = f(\{\delta_i\}) = \mathbb N.$$
6. If $a_n = b_{n'}$, from 4., there exist $i, i' \in \mathbb N$ such that $a_n = f(\delta_i)$ and $b_{n'} = f(\delta_{i'})$. From 5., it is enforced that $i = i'$. From the construction, this means that both $\delta_i$ and $\delta_i t$ are integers, hence $t \in \mathbb Q$, but this is impossible. Hence, $\{a_n\} \cap \{b_n\} = \varnothing$. Similarly, we have $$\{a_n\} \cap \{b_n\} = \{b_n\} \cap \{c_n\} = \{a_n\} \cap \{c_n\} = \varnothing.$$

This ends the proof of your conjecture.

**Remarks, specializations and generalizations:**

Playing with the "construct a floor function $f$ and record points where it jumped" trick as above by changing the function $f$, there are other things you can say:

- (From @Jyrki Lahtonen) Classic Beatty's theorem says, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are irrationals satisfying $$\frac1\alpha + \frac1\beta = 1$$, then $\lfloor n\alpha\rfloor$ and $\lfloor n\beta\rfloor$ forms a partition of $\mathbb N$. A little computation indicates $\alpha = 1 + \tau$ and $\beta = 1+\tau^{-1}$ for some irrational $\tau$. Rewrite $\lfloor n\alpha \rfloor = \lfloor n\rfloor+\lfloor n\tau\rfloor$ and $\lfloor n\beta \rfloor = \lfloor n\rfloor+\lfloor n\tau^{-1}\rfloor$, and consider the function $$f(\delta) = \lfloor\delta\rfloor + \lfloor\delta\tau\rfloor,$$ one can prove the classic Beatty theorem (probably this is not the proof of Beatty theorem most people know, at least I did not know at the beginning).
- Consider the function $$f(\delta) = \left\lfloor \delta\frac{t_1}{t_1}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \delta\frac{t_2}{t_1}\right\rfloor + \cdots + \left\lfloor \delta\frac{t_k}{t_1}\right\rfloor,$$ your last statement can be proved:

> $\{a_i(n)\}$, $i = 1, \cdots, k$ forms a partition of $\mathbb N$, where $$a_i(n) = \sum_{j=1}^k \left\lfloor n\frac{t_j}{t_i}\right\rfloor.$$

- Pass to infinity. By considering the function $$f(\delta) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \delta \tau^{-i}\right\rfloor,$$ we can prove the following:

> Let $\tau > 1$ be transcendental (like $\pi$; this is sufficient but not likely to be necessary). Then $$\mathbb N = \bigcup_{j=0}^\infty A_j, \quad A_{j} \cap A_{j'} = \varnothing \text{ if $j \neq j'$},$$ where $A_j = \{a_j^n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, and $$a_j^n = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \lfloor n\tau^{j-i}\rfloor.$$

This gives another proof that you can accommodate (countably) infinite travelers in infinitely many hotels, each hotel have infinitely many rooms, so that all rooms are occupied (i.e. the $\mathbb N = \mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ problem). This proof is neater than what I knew (the square grid trick), in my opinion.

You can further generalize by changing the sequence $\{\tau^i\}$ into other infinite sequence, but the descriptions get uglier and I will omit it.

Comment: It really is this simple. Well done. If I got it right: A) You only need $t^2$ to be irrational. B) A simpler form of the same argument would prove that the sequences
$d_n=n+\lfloor n/t\rfloor$ and $e_n=n+\lfloor tn\rfloor$ also partition the naturals. Of course, $d$- and $e$-sequences form a Beatty pair. C) Generalization to four or more sequences comes naturally as long as we assume that relevant powers of $t$ are all irrational. My upvote was already there.

Comment: Obviously need $t$ to be irrational in my item B.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I think you are right.

Comment: How to prove that no integer number will  appear both in $a_n$ and $b_n$?

Comment: $f(\delta)$ belongs to $\{a_n\}$ when $\delta t^2$ is an integer, and belongs to $\{b_n\}$ when $\delta t$ is an integer, the two events will not concur at the same $\delta$. Felt guilty for not being able to edit in Jyrki's bounty period, but your general statement also comes from the same idea, and I will expand it when I have time.

Comment: @Hw Chu It's easy to prove $a_n \not = b_n$ , but we need to prove $a_n \not = b_m$ for all $m,n\in N$

Comment: My argument above actually proved that $\{a_n\} \cap \{b_n\}$ is the empty set.

Comment: @Hw Chu but  $n$ is integer, not increase continuously

Comment: Sorry, I still think you didn't prove $\{a_n\} \cap \{b_n\}$ is the empty set, and didn't prove every integer will appear in one of $a_n,b_n,c_n$.

Comment: Very nice answer! +1. @Next the argument is definitely correct. Here are some details. Let $\delta_1,\delta_2,\dots$ be the values of $\delta$ for which one of $\delta,\delta t,\delta t^2$ is an integer. What "$f(\delta)$ increases by exactly 1 after each step" means is that $f(\delta_1)=1,f(\delta_2)=2,f(\delta_3)=3,\dots$. We also have: if $\delta_n$ is an integer, $f(\delta_n) \in \{c_1,c_2,\dots\}$; if $t\delta_n$ is an integer, $f(\delta_n) \in \{b_1,b_2,\dots\}$; if $t^2\delta_n$ is an integer, $f(\delta_n) \in \{a_1,a_2,\dots\}$. First of all, since $f(\delta_n) = n$ for each $n$,

Comment: clearly $\{a_n\}\cup\{b_n\}\cup\{c_n\} = \mathbb{N}$. Second of all, each $a_n$ is achieved as $f(\delta_k)$ for some $\delta_k$; indeed, for $\delta_k = \frac{n}{t^2}$. Similarly with $b_n$ and $c_n$. So, if some $a_n$ were equal to some $b_m$, we would have to have $\frac{n}{t^2}$ and $\frac{m}{t}$ be an integer simultaneously, which is impossible, since $t$ is irrational. This is (one of the three cases) why "no two of $\delta, \delta t, \delta t^2$ will hit an integer at the same time".

Comment: @mathworker21 Can you post an answer for $n=100$ and $t=\pi$?

Comment: @mathworker21 I mean why $100$ appear exactly once in one of $a_n,b_n,c_n$

Comment: @Next dude. read what Hw Chu wrote and what i wrote, and think about it. I spent my time typing up all of those details for you. cmon

Comment: Thank you mathworker21 for editing and the comments. I have made another edition and hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

*Often it's crucial how a question is formulated to understand it well. My following considerations involve a functional view. It's a proof for the generalisation.*

$k\in\mathbb{N}~$ fixed.

$t_i\in\mathbb{R}^+~$ and $~\displaystyle t_i,\frac{t_j}{t_i}|_{j\neq i}~$ are irrational for all $~i,j\in\{1,2,...,k\}~\quad\quad (1)$

Let $~\displaystyle f(x):=\sum\limits_{j=1}^k\lfloor t_j\,x\rfloor~$ with $~x\in\mathbb{R}_0^+~$ . $~~~$ *Note:* $~\displaystyle a_i(n) \equiv f\left(\frac{n}{t_i}\right)$

It follows $~f(x_1)\leq f(x_2)~$ for all $~x_1\leq x_2~ . \hspace{4.7cm} (2)$

Define $~0~$ as a infinitesimal small positive value as a simplification for "choosing always a sufficient small value" as it is used in the sense of mathematical border processes for the left side $~x\to a-0~$ and for the right side $~x\to a+0~$ . $\hspace{4cm} (3)$

It means $~n=\lfloor n-0\rfloor + 1 ~$ for all natural $~n~$ .

Note: *If someone has a problem with such a use of $~0~$ then it's better to define $~\delta>0~$ as a infinite small value so that $~n=\lfloor n-\delta\rfloor + 1 ~$ and substitute $~0~$ by $~\delta~$. But then the argumentation always has to be supplemented by $~\delta\to 0 ~$.*

$\text{(A)}$

Because of $~(1)~$ we have $~\displaystyle\frac{n_1}{t_{i_1}}\neq\frac{n_2}{t_{i_2}}~$ for $~i_1\neq i_2~$ and $n_1, n_2\in\mathbb{N}~$, $~$ and

together with $~(2)~$ and $~(3)~$ we get $~\displaystyle f\left(\frac{n}{t_i}\right) = f\left(\frac{n-0}{t_i}\right) + 1~$; $~$ it follows:

> $$\{f(x)\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R}_0^+\}=\mathbb{N}_0$$

In words: $~f(x)~$ grows always by $~1~$, $\,$there is never a jump of $~2~$ or more.

And $~\displaystyle f\left(\frac{n}{t_i}\right)-n = f\left(\frac{n-0}{t_i}\right)-\lfloor n-0\rfloor~$ tells us that $~f(x)~$ can only grow,

if at least one of it's components $~\left\lfloor t_j\,x\right\rfloor~$ grows:

> $$\left\{f\left(\frac{n}{t_i}\right)|\,i\in\{1,2,...,k\}\right\}=\{f(x)\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R}_0^+\}$$

$\text{(B)}$

Because of $~(1)~$ we have $~\displaystyle\left|\frac{n_1}{t_{i_1}}-\frac{n_2}{t_{i_2}}\right|>0~$ for $~i_1\neq i_2~$ and $n_1, n_2\in\mathbb{N}~$ .

E.g. we choose $~\displaystyle\frac{n_1}{t_{i_1}}<\frac{n_2}{t_{i_2}}~$ and with $~(3)~$ we get $~\displaystyle\frac{n_1}{t_{i_1}}<\frac{n_2-0}{t_{i_2}}~$ .

Assume that $~\displaystyle f\left(\frac{n_1}{t_{i_1}}\right) = f\left(\frac{n_2}{t_{i_2}}\right)~$ .

Then we get $~\displaystyle f\left(\frac{n_1}{t_{i_1}}\right) = f\left(\frac{n_2-0}{t_{i_2}}\right) + 1~$ 
which means $~\displaystyle f\left(\frac{n_1}{t_{i_1}}\right) > f\left(\frac{n_2-0}{t_{i_2}}\right)~$ .

But this is a $\,$*contradiction*$\,$ to $~(2)~$ , $~$ so that we have

> $$\left\{f\left(\frac{n_1}{t_{i_1}}\right)\right\}\cap\left\{f\left(\frac{n_2}{t_{i_2}}\right)\right\} = \emptyset$$

for all $~i_1\neq i_2~$ and $n_1, n_2\in\mathbb{N}~$ .

With $\text{(A)}$ and $\text{(B)}$ follows, that the claim is correct.