# Pairwise disjoint sets of the form $\{\lfloor n\alpha \rfloor : n \in \mathbb{N}\}.$

Tags: number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $S_{\alpha} = \{\lfloor n\alpha \rfloor : n \in \mathbb{N}\}.$ I am working on a problem which asks to show that $\mathbb{N}$ cannot be partitioned as the pairwise disjoint union of $S_{\alpha}, S_{\beta}, S_{\gamma}$ for some $\alpha, \beta, \gamma.$ I am familiar with Beatty sequences, but this problem is slightly different.

To start attacking this problem, I first wish to place conditions under which $S_{\alpha}, S_{\beta}$ are disjoint. Let $S = \frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{\beta}.$ If disjointness is equivalent to $S = 1$ and $\alpha, \beta$ being irrational, we would be done by Beatty's Theorem. I have shown $S_{\alpha}, S_{\beta}$ intersect if $S>1.$ I have also shown they intersect if one of $\alpha, \beta$ is rational. But what if $S<1$? It seems counterintuitive that making the sequences less dense would still allow them to intersect, no matter how small $S$ is. But whenever I test $2$ sequences on Desmos with various small values of $S,$ they always overlap. This is my only justification for why the result must be true.

Here is my attempt at finding an intersection: $\alpha, \beta$ being irrational and $\lfloor \alpha n \rfloor = \lfloor \beta m \rfloor = k$ is equivalent to $\frac{k}{\alpha} < n < \frac{k+1}{\alpha}, \frac{k}{\beta} < m < \frac{k+1}{\beta}.$ If we add the $2$ equations, we get $kS < m+n < (k+1)S.$ Since $S < 1,$ we can certainly find integers $m,n, k$ to satisfy this. But we cannot proceed backwards because only $2$ inequalities have been satisfied while we need $4.$ How should I proceed? Any hints?

Update: I have solved the original problem with a different method, but I'm still curious about the answer to this question.

Comment: For a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{N}$ if $d(A)=\lim_{n\rightarrow}\frac{|A\cap[1,n]|}{n}$ exists then $d(A)+d(\mathbb{N}\setminus A)=1$. Now you can show that $d(S_{\alpha})=\frac{1}{\alpha}$ and hence if $S_{\alpha},S_{\beta}$ partition $\mathbb{N}$ we should have $\frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{\beta}=1$. $d(A)$ is known as natural density of $A$. For details see the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya $S_{\alpha}, S_{\beta}$ do not partition $\mathbb{N}.$ I am investigating conditions under which $S_{\alpha}, S_{\beta}$ are merely disjoint.

Comment: [A generalization of Beatty](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3390407/11619) into a different direction.

Comment: Okay. But I think you can use the concept of natural density.

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya Look up [Beatty sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence) to not be at a disadvantage here.

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya I already used it to show that they are not disjoint if $\frac{1}{\alpha} + \frac{1}{\beta} > 1.$ But it does not help at all in the case $S<1.$

Comment: Yeah, I got it.

Comment: If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are a Beatty pair, then surely $S_\alpha$ and $S_{2\beta}$ are distinct. Not that it would help you in finding a $\gamma$ :-(

Comment: Or generalizing that trivial observation: If $(\alpha,\beta)$ is a Beatty pair, then $S_{n\alpha}\cap S_{m\beta}=\emptyset$ for all pairs $m,n>0$.

Comment: I have asked a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3730241/inequality-frac1-alpha-frac1-beta-leq-frac4n24n2-1-related-to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned about Beatty sequences from Joe Roberts' excellent book [Elementary number theory - a problem oriented approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262680289). There he cites a theorem due to Skolem (1957).

> There do not exist positive irrational numbers $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ such that $S_\alpha$, $S_\beta$ and $S_\gamma$ would be pairwise disjoint.

An earlier (1927) result by Uspensky states that it is impossible to find $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ such that $S_\alpha$, $S_\beta$, $S_\gamma$ would form a partition on $\Bbb{Z}_{>0}$. I'm fairly sure that the link on [WP on Beatty sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence) is exactly the reference.

Roberts has listed both these results as exercises (he builds up to the proofs by sequences of exercises). I'm not sure I have the time to get to the heart of the matter :-( Anyway, here is the sequence of exercises leading to Uspensky's theorem. If I got it right, the approach is due to R.L. Graham (1963)

Assume $\alpha<\beta<\gamma$. Let $m$ be the smallest natural number not in $S_\alpha$.

1. $\alpha=1+\delta$ where $0<\delta<1$.
2. $S_\alpha$ does not miss any pair of consecutive integers.
3. $(m-1)\delta<1\le m\delta$.
4. $m$ is the first element of $S_\beta$ and $\beta=m+\epsilon, 0\le\epsilon<1$.
5. If $x$ is a positive integer $\notin S_\alpha$, then the next integer $\notin S_\alpha$ is either $x+m$ or $x+m+1$.
6. The next element in $S_\beta$ after $\lfloor n\beta\rfloor$ is either $\lfloor n\beta\rfloor+m$ or $\lfloor n\beta\rfloor+m+1$.
7. The $k$th positive integer missing from $S_\alpha$ is the $k$th element in $S_\beta$. The claim follows.

Comment: In terms of solving the original problem, this doesn't help since the problem was surely not meant to be solved by appealing to a theorem stronger than it. In terms of determining when $S_{\alpha}, S_{\beta}$ are disjoint, this doesn't help either.

Comment: @Displayname I realize that this is not very useful as an answer for the reason you explained. If everything else fails, you can check out Roberts' book. [A free download](https://archive.org/details/ElementaryNumberTheory_841) seems to be available. Or check out the reference to Uspensky's paper in WP.

Comment: @Displayname The approach seems to be that when $S_\alpha$, $\alpha\in(1,2)$ and $S_\beta$ do not intersect, and $S_\beta$ contains the smallest integer missing from $S_\alpha$, then they must partition $\Bbb{Z}_{>0}$ already - leaving no room for $S_\gamma$.